# jQuery Grep in Multidimensional Array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, grep

I have an array that looks like this:

```
car1: 2
car2: 3
truck: 1
bike: 2
```

Now want to filter the array with jQuery grep to only see car elements.

```
var r = jQuery.grep(arr, function(a) {
    return a.indexOf('car') === 0;
});
```

But my array is empty afterwards. What do I need to do in order to grep/filter the array correctly?

Comment: The data you have provided is not an array. I am confused. Are you trying to get the values associated with the properties on an object that contain the string 'car'?

Comment: actually the array / object contains the cookies that are set for this page (var arr = jQuery.cookie();) and I want to have the same array but only containing for example the car elements

Comment: What does the data structure actually look like? `[{car1: 2}, {car2: 3} ....]` or `{car1: 2, car2: 3, ...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether your data is actually an array of objects, or if it is a single object with multiple properties, here is a solution for each.

```js
// solution for array of objects
var elems = [{car1: 2}, {car2: 3}, {truck: 1}, {bike: 2}];
var filtered = elems.reduce(function (result, current) {
  var isCar = Object.keys(current).some(function (key){
    return key.indexOf("car") > -1;
  });
  if (isCar) {
    result.push(current);
  }
  return result;
}, []);
// returns an array of "car" objects
console.log(filtered)

// solution for single object with multiple properties
var elems2 = {car1: 2, car2: 3, truck: 1, bike: 2};
var filtered2 = Object.keys(elems2).reduce(function (result, current) {
  var isCar = current.indexOf("car") > -1;
  if (isCar) {
    result[current] = elems2[current];
  }
  return result;
}, {});
// returns single object with only "car" properties and their values
console.log(filtered2)
```